# OpenSSL Basic Constraints

Tags: openssl, certificate-authority, server

I have been working through the book '[Planning for PKI](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471397024.html)' and I have gotten to the point where I want to create an end-entity certificate. However, I am faced with an error message saying that there are extension errors inside the certificate. I have been guided by my teacher to look closely at how the basic constraint extension can be altered to fix this issue.

The book recommends against the use of the Basic Constraint extension in end entity certificates. However, when I simply delete it, a default extension of "`CA:TRUE`" is inserted anyway.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to override this automatic insertion or did I misunderstood the book?
2. Any ideas as to what I may be doing wrong?

The below is the extension I have been using to create the certificate:

```
[ server_ext ]
basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false
nsCertType              = server
subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid,issuer:always
keyUsage                = critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage        = serverAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the openSSL man pages might be of some assistance:

> If the basicConstraints extension is absent then the certificate is considered to be a "possible CA" other extensions are checked according to the intended use of the certificate. A warning is given in this case because the certificate should really not be regarded as a CA: however it is allowed to be a CA to work around some broken software.

i.e. the KeyUsage/ExtendedKeyUsage would (it seems) be used to guess.

Taken from https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/x509.html, Certificate Extensions section.

This seems (to me) to be different to what the openssl cookbook says (https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-openssl.html):

> The Basic Constraints extension is used to mark certificates as belonging to a CA, giving them the ability to sign other certificates. Non-CA certificates will either have this extension omitted or will have the value of CA set to FALSE. This extension is critical, which means that all software-consuming certificates must understand its meaning.

Checking the man page for x509v3_config (https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html - see Standard Extensions section), one possible issue is your syntax.

They provide the following as their examples:

```
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE

basicConstraints=CA:FALSE

basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE, pathlen:0
```

They provide one additional way of achieving similar results:

```
basicConstraints=critical,@bs_section

[bs_section]

CA=true
pathlen=1
```

I would just amend your config to read:

`basicConstraints=CA:FALSE`

In place of:

`basicConstraints        = critical,CA:false`

This way, your profile is explicit, and should override any other (possibly opposite) config being applied elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer. However, I have checked my current certificate and the syntax is correct. It also recognises various changes to the Basic Constraint with the tabulated syntax rather than a single space.

I was hoping it would be something I haven't added rather than incorrectly applying the settings I currently have as that is unlikely to be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to override the default functionality that included the Basic Constraint when it was missing from the extension. It was to do with the csr and copy extensions attribute in the openssl.cnf file.